# Getting property through attribute name

Tags: c#, attributes

I am trying to set a value for a property in a class for which I have only attribute information available as input. I am using below code to parse through all the attributes of all the properties in the class and to find a match on my input. Is there a better way to set the property value without iterating through all properties of the class? Maybe just get the property from the attribute name.

```cs
var classA = new MyClass();

string str = "MYDouble";
string value = "0.3";

foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in classA.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    object[] attribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true);

    if (attribute.Length > 0)
    {
        MyCustomAttribute myAttribute = (MyCustomAttribute) attribute[0];
        string propertyValue = myAttribute.Name;

        if (propertyValue.Equals(str))
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(classA, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
        }                       
    }
}
```

I want something like this if it is possible

```
var propertyInfo= classA.GetPropertyInfoBasedOnAttribute("MyDouble");
propertyInfo.SetValue(value.... same as above)
```

Comment: "attribute information available as input", can you explain more what this means?

Comment: If you mean, I want to look up which property has attribute X with value Y, then no, there's no such lookup, you will have to iterate over the properties at least one. You can build this lookup yourself, however.

Comment: string str = "MYDouble"; is my input which is availble to me , I need to find a property with this attribute and set its value to 0.3.

Comment: Then I guess what you have is the best you can do as a one-off operation, if you intend to do this a lot I would create a dictionary of string->PropertyInfo so that you can look it up in that much quicker.

Comment: I used attribute and reflection to just avoid making a lookup:-)

Comment: This would be much easier to understand if you included an example of something with the attribute.

Comment: @ScottHannen updated my expectation.

Comment: I think what Lasse was saying was that you should use a dictionary and store the results you look up by class type so that you don't have to do the reflection each time. Once you do reflection and find the property, store it in a dictionary. Each time, check the dictionary first so you don't repeat that reflection. A lot of code that does reflection works like that. Whatever the type of `classA` is, if you get another object of the same type it will have the same properties with the same attributes, so there's no need to scan the properties every time.